# В бэкграунде качать xml-файл и показывать сообщение

Tags: ios

Возможно ли такое сделать в *iOS8+*?

Приложение в *бэкграунде* раз в определенное время (30 минут, к примеру) качает с сервера *xml-файл*, парсит его, и, если нужно, выдает пользователю сообщение с текстом и кнопкой *ОК*.

Такое возможно сделать?

Знаю, что можно без проблем в *статусбаре* показывать *нотификейшн*, но так не нужно. Да и на счет *бэкгранунда* не уверен, что можно такое делать. В Андроиде - без проблем это все можно делать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Технически, это можно сделать ([вот мануал](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)), но по уму этого делать не стоит. Зачем жрать батарейку / трафик, не давать телефону заснуть и раз в полчаса качать файл, который с некоторой долей вероятности никак не поменялся, если можно сделать так:

- есть сервер, который либо знает, что что-то случилось и поменялось, потому что это ваш сервер, на котором формируется ваш XML файл, либо тупо проверяет состояние XML файла, если это не ваш файл, а чужой, на чужом сервере.
- как только сервер определил изменение файла, он посылает Push Message в вашу аппликацию на телефоне, которая спокойно спит. iOS разбудит аппликацию, выдаст ей информацию из Push Message, аппликация скачает требуемый файл. Если нужно, она может показать и Notification (в баре, на иконке и т.п.), но может и не показывать.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Способ, которые Вы предложили будет лучше) Попробую его использовать!

Comment: А по поводу уведомления, возможно ли выдавать сообщение с текстом и кнопкой ОК, по нажатию на которую пользователь перейдет на определенный экран в приложении ?

Comment: Вам какое-нибудь приложение на iOS (или Android) такие уведомления выдавало? ВНЕ приложения так нельзя. Можно показать разные штуки в notification bar, можно показать "красный кружочек", но залепить в лицо пользователю алерт "Ай-ай-ай, кнопка нажми, да?" может только сама ОС. Так что придется пользователю среагировать на привычный, спокойный notification, после чего открыть аппу и уже там можете забросать его любым количеством диалогов, кнопок и чего у вас там есть в арсенале.

Comment: это же приложение под Андроид выдает уведомление по типу: http://osamashabrez.com/assets/default-Alertdialog.png

Comment: Но не совсем просто это реализовано) На самом то деле, из бэкграунда вызывается не алертдиалог, а активити, что в целом обычное дело. И это активити имеет вид обычного алертдиалога:)

Comment: Я открыл вопрос, чтобы выяснить можно ли из бэкграунда показывать алертдиалог:)